# PN Junction diode depletion width

Tags: semiconductor-physics

depletion width formula of a pn junction diode has V(barrier)-V(external) i.e [image]

if the barrier potential is 0.6v(say) and i apply a forward voltage of 1V, then as per the calculation Width becomes imaginary.

could somebody help me in understanding this...

[image]

Comment: Please quote that *depletion width formula* within your question,
so that it will be clear what you are talking about.

Comment: Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead. Please also be more specific about *what it is* that you want to understand here, i.e. ask a *specific question* instead of a general request for explanation

Comment: Done Thomas... please let me know in case the question is still not clear

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for the depletion zone width is only valid for $V_a \lt \phi$.

As we increase $V_a$ from zero towards $\phi$ the depletion zone shrinks until it disappears at $V_a = \phi$. For higher values of $V_a$ the depletion zone no longer exists so it is meaningless to ask what its width is.

The imaginary value you are getting is the result of using the equation in a regime for which the equation does not apply.